# local.ERROR: BadMethodCallException: Method [validateTextRequired] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am trying to submit a form data using Laravel controller. But I got this error while submit

> local.ERROR: BadMethodCallException: Method [validateTextRequired] does not exist.

**controller.php**

```php
$this->validate($request, [
    'photo'                    => 'required|mimes:jpg,gif,png,jpe,jpeg',
    'title'                    => 'required|min:3|max:45',
    'name'                     => 'required',
    'address'                  => 'required',
    'city'                     => 'required',
    'tribe'                    => 'required',
    'language'                 => 'required',
    'country'                  => 'required',
    'student_id'               => 'required',
    'tribe_university_name'    => 'required',
    'student_program_of_study' => 'required',
    'faculty'                  => 'required',
    'bank_name'                => 'required',
    'account_number'           => 'required',
    'address'                  => 'required',
    'swift_code'               => 'required',
    'routing_number'           => 'required',
    // 'categories_id'  => 'required',
    'goal'                     => 'required|integer|max:' . $this->settings->max_campaign_amount . '|min:' . $this->settings->min_campaign_amount,
    'description'              => 'text_required|required|min:20',

]);

if ($this->request->hasFile('photo')) {

    $image = $request->photo->store('public/images');
}

$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
$user->address = trim($this->request->address);
$user->city = trim($this->request->city);
$user->tribe = trim($this->request->tribe);
$user->tribe_university_name = trim($this->request->tribe_university_name);
$user->student_program_of_study = trim($this->request->student_program_of_study);
$user->faculty = trim($this->request->faculty);
$user->level = trim($this->request->level);

$user->save();

return $id_campaign;
```

Can't solve the problem. Anybody help please ?

Comment: `'description'  => 'text_required|required|min:20',` There is no rule `text_required`. Should that just be `required`?

Comment: yes I have changed that now...but no change of error

Comment: Your rule is now `'description' => 'required|min:20',`, and you're still getting "Method [validateTextRequired] does not exist."? I find that unlikely, unless you're using `text_required` somewhere else.

Comment: Yes ... it's done :)...thanks a lot brother.